# Etymological Dictionary: German to English

Tags: german-to-english, dictionary

Is there a German to English dictionary where word origins of German words are also given? I am looking for a modern etymological dictionary. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only can have it separately. On one side there are lots of good translation dictionaries for German to English (and also English to German) like

- [Pons](https://de.pons.com/shop/volltextsuche.do?produktsuche=1&keyword=W%C3%B6rterbuch%20englisch&index=pons) or
- [Langenscheid](https://www.langenscheidt.com/englisch/schule-studium-woerterbuch)

and many others, and there are etymological dictionaries like

- [Konrad Duden's Herkunftswörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/Shop/Das-Herkunftsworterbuch-1) or
- [Friedrich Kluge's Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/42888?rskey=MjzbBA&result=3)

on the other side. Both classes of dictionaries are very specialized, and I do not believe that you will find a high-quality combination of both of them.

But there are also lots of online resources for translation dictionaries like

- [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/) and
- [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc)

and also online resources where you can find etymological facts about lots of German words like

- [German version of Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite) or
- [Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache (DWDS)](https://www.dwds.de)